# How to stop creating database again in the windows phone when the emulator is closed

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

I am working on the windows phone. The problem I am facing is whenever my Emulator is closed the database that was created by me is destroyed and next time the emulator starts again, a new database is created.

What I want is that the database should be created once and the data not erased when I re-open my emulator.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Here is my code for creating the database in windows phone

```
 public class PersonalDataContext : DataContext
{
    public static string DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/PersonalReminderDatabase.sdf";

    public PersonalDataContext(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
        if (this.DatabaseExists() == false)
        {
            this.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you use an external database for testing/development?

Comment: No sir my database is created in the emulator i just want that whenever I open my emulator  reminder set by me must be shown  as i am working on reminder app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When ever you closed the emulator, the application that you have deployed on the emulator gets uninstalled & on restarting the emulator it gets re-installed, so the database that you create doesn't stay on the emulator if you close and reopen. And currently there is no way you can get the database back from restarting the emulator. So the best possible way is that you test you application on an external database or on a device. Here are some links that will help you understand; [Windows Phone Emulators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402563%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) & [How to Deploy & Run App on Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). Hope this helps.

Comment: More exact - the emulator is reset to the known system image. Like reformating the computer. So you can make crap in a program and on the next run it works nice agin - perfect for programming.

Answer (score 0):

In the emulator you can make a checkpoint of your image...then make it the default.  If you do that, your state of your emulator should be preserved to the point of the checkpoint.